# How do I quickly know what types questions I can ask on a given StackExchange website?

Tags: feature-request

I had a question about NFC and I wasn't sure what SE site would be appropriate to ask it on. I knew that information was documented somewhere but it took me a few minutes to find it.

"Asks Different's" web page header (see below) includes the sub-line "Answers For Your Apple Questions". That instantly told me that the Ask Different webpage would be the incorrect place to post the question.

This alleviated me from having to dig around in the documentation to find what is allowed and what isn't.

Why isn't this standardize across all SE websites?

[image]

Comment: The information you seek is actually in the help center of every Stack Exchange website.

Comment: @Ramhound - yes I eventually found it. The point behind my question is that a SE website name should give an idea of types of questions that are allowed to be asked therein.

Comment: @Niko_Jako for most sites it is in the URL. For example https://aviation.stackexchange.com/ is unlikely to be about fishing. The exceptions are for [The Original Trilogy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61541/where-do-the-names-of-the-stack-overflow-trilogy-sites-come-from), [apple.se] (which is still partly obvious by the URL) and [ubuntu.se] (same as Apple). A quick glance at the actual questions on any site should tell you what is on topic.

Answer (score 3):

Every site has a [Help Centre](https://superuser.com/help). You will find this by clicking on the Stack icon at the top right of every page on every site.

[image]

In that help centre is a section on asking questions.

Within that section will be a page titled "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)"

That page may or may not be pinned to the top of the list but it is **always** at `https://{site}.com/help/on-topic`